# Ler se a variavel é inteiro ou nao, incluindo: 1.00

Tags: php-7, float, int, number-format

Eu fiz um sistema que lê se a variável é inteiro ou não, o único problema é que quando a variável é 1.0 ele le como inteiro sendo que é um decimal. Como posso fazer pra corrigir?

```
$n = 1.2;

if((int)$n) != $n) {
   Não é um inteiro // 1.2
   } else {
   É um inteiro // 1.0
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a ler o 1.0 ou os demais números que terminam em .0 em decimais?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Então, você pode usar a função [gettype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) que retorna o tipo da variável, depois é só você checar se esse tipo é igual à `"integer"`.

```php
$n = 1.2;

if(gettype($n) != "integer") {
   Não é um inteiro // 1.2
   } else {
   É um inteiro // 1.0
}
```

Mas seguindo o seu raciocínio, seria possível converter para `int` e depois converter ambos para `string` e compará-los, assim você estaria comparando `"1" == "1.0"`, que é falso.

```php
$n = 1.2;

if((string)(int)$n != (string)$n) {
   Não é um inteiro // 1.2
   } else {
   É um inteiro // 1.0
}
```